# I have an incorrect Query but I am not able to find the error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Kills DESC) pos FROM kills) WHERE `UUID` = ?
```

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `UUID` = '37bb2c2c-e170-469c-a08e-6a22e7d083cd'' at line 1
```

I have no idea how to fix the error, because I dont know the error.

Comment: Do you need to name your subselect? `(SELECT ...) AS x`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns from the subquery then you don't need the outer query:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Kills DESC) pos FROM kills WHERE `UUID` = ?
```

If you want to keep it as it is you must alias the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Kills DESC) pos FROM kills) t WHERE `UUID` = ?
```